# What's the cheapest and easiest way to fix stains from corrosive solution?

Tags: staining, veneer

I have this bathroom/laundry sink that goes on top of a vanity cabinet with what I believe to be a layer of fake veneer. I've had noticed these light stains a while ago, probably from small spills of some corrosive solution I used to clean some rust from metal bits a couple of month ago.

I would like suggestions on the cheapest and easiest way to fix, thanks.

[image]

Comment: Search for white stains and you will find many possible fixes to try. But top looks like melamine as used in kitchens, so maybe this can't be fixed.

Comment: Highly unlikely this is wood veneer.   Nobody with any sense would build a vanity top with a wood veneer surface, so I think the first two commenters are right, and it's a phenolic laminate.  That, and given what you think caused the spots (a caustic solution), probably means they are not stains, but rather bleaching of the laminate.   I doubt you're going be able to repair it in a way that matches the surface any better than the spots do.

Comment: Based upon the comments and your description of 'fake veneer', I agree that this question fits better in the DYI site and will transfer it there. Good luck getting answers.